# Uppercase only verdana font

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop

Where can I find a verdana font for ttf that is only uppercase?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the existing Verdana font and your caps lock key?

Comment: It does sound almost Too simple